# How can i get the raw data from camera on android platform?

Tags: android, camera

I want to get the raw data  by specified camera and specified LED , Because the device I'm using has two rear-facing cameras ,And set the camera not to focus automatically.

Comment: Are you using `Camera` API ? Or `Intent` for Camera ? Put some code indicating the problem .

Comment: I finished getting the data but I wanted to know how to control the dual rear-facing camera.